# Cannot restore minimized program from Windows Taskbar

Tags: windows, delphi, taskbar

My program is written in Delphi 10. It shows a login dialog before it actually starts, and everything works fine.

But if I minimize the program by clicking on the Windows Taskbar (while login dialog active), it will remain minimized forever.

Does anyone knows the solution ?

Unit1.pas

```
class function TForm1.Execute: Boolean;
var
 Dlg:TForm1;
begin
 Dlg:=TForm1.Create(nil);
 try
   Result:=Dlg.ShowModal=mrOk;
 finally
  Dlg.Free;
 end;
end;
```

Project1.dpr

```
begin
  if not TForm1.Execute then //if i press on task bar, window will remain minimized forever.
   Exit;
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True; 
  //Moving TForm1.Execute here has no effect
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.Run;
end
```

Comment: Why are you using the same class for both a modal dialog and the MainForm? This code makes no sense.

Comment: It's just an example to reproduce error. Renaming class will not solve this problem.

Comment: You should let the application initialise and run Application.CreateForm _before_ you have `if not TForm1.Execute...` it would also be better to use the application created instance, so using Execute as an object method, not a class method.

Comment: Hello, can you post a brief example? I dont clearly understand how to create form with Application.CreateForm and exit program in case of modal result of this form is mrCancel

Comment: What happens if you create the main form before the login form?

Comment: It will show a window with error, since no user credentials entered.

Comment: Is it correct that TForm1 is used for both the login dialog and the main form? At first glance, I would create different forms for login and as mainform.

Comment: No it doesn't show a window with error because your code doesn't check user credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a sample code showing how to have a login form shown BEFORE main form. I checked (Win10) that minimizing the window with task bar click, it can be reactivated with task bar click.

In the login form, I just made it with two buttons, one for login OK and one for login failed, without actuallu checking any usercode/password. I assumed you was able to do that part.

**Project file:**

```
program LoginDemo;
uses
  Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.Controls,
  LoginDemoMain in 'LoginDemoMain.pas' {DemoMainForm},
  LoginDemoDialog in 'LoginDemoDialog.pas' {DemoLoginForm};
{$R *.res}
begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TDemoLoginForm, DemoLoginForm);
  try
      if DemoLoginForm.ShowModal <> mrOK then begin
          ShowMessage('Invalid login, sorry...');
          Exit;
      end;
  finally
      DemoLoginForm.Free;
  end;
  Application.CreateForm(TDemoMainForm, DemoMainForm);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

**Login dialog:**

```
unit LoginDemoDialog;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TDemoLoginForm = class(TForm)
    LoginOKButton: TButton;
    LoginFailedButton: TButton;
    Label1: TLabel;
    procedure LoginFailedButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure LoginOKButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  DemoLoginForm: TDemoLoginForm;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TDemoLoginForm.LoginFailedButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
    Close;
    ModalResult := mrCancel;
end;

procedure TDemoLoginForm.LoginOKButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
    Close;
    ModalResult := mrOK;
end;

end.
```

**Main form:**

```
unit LoginDemoMain;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TDemoMainForm = class(TForm)
    Label1: TLabel;
    ExitButton: TButton;
    procedure ExitButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  DemoMainForm: TDemoMainForm;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TDemoMainForm.ExitButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
    Close;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Hello, seems like your answer only works partially, since first form creatred with Application.CreateForm is assigned to readonly Application.MainForm property. This cannot be changed later. You can review source of Application.Create form or http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.MainForm#Code_Examples<br> I don't quite understand the implications of this

Comment: The first call to `Application.CreateForm()` establishes the `Application.MainForm`, and when that Form closes, the app terminates.  For splash/login Forms created *before* the desired `MainForm` is created, you must `Create` them manually instead, eg: `DemoLoginForm := TDemoLoginForm.Create(nil);` Otherwise, create the `MainForm` first, but set `Application.ShowMainForm := False` before calling `Application.Run()`, and then call `Application.MainForm.Show()` when needed.

Comment: I did exacly the same in my TForm1.Execute class function, Dlg:=TForm1.Create(nil); That worked fine, but login form can not be restored if minimized.

Comment: @Valeriy.B Sorry, you are wrong. After the login form is freed and TDemoMainForm instance is created, this one becomes the main form. You can see that easily with the debugger: put a breakpoint on the line with Application.Run and CTRL-F7 to show Application.Mainform.Name and you'll see that the mainform is now DemoMainForm.

Comment: @fpiette Yes, you are right. Thanks for help. Well, i changed the way i create login dialog instance in my Execute class function to Application.CreateForm and moved to correct location in .dpr file.

Comment: I'm sure @Remy is right here and that this code just makes the login form be the main form. Which cannot be the desired outcome. It doesn't feel like this question has been answered satisfactorily.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The login form becomes the main form for the duration of the login process. Right after login, the login form is freed and either the program exits (invalid login) or (valid login) the TDemoMainForm is created and become the main form as expected. Despite the login form being main form, the application doesn't close when freed because that behavior is in Application.Run which is not running yet (That is why Remy first sentence is wrong). At anytime, taskbar can be used to minimize the visible window and that is what the OP asked.